# Is IE8 going to break my CDN hosted jQuery?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, cdn

IE8 has a feature called [InPrivate Filtering](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/08/25/ie8-and-privacy.aspx), which will block scripts it finds on webpages from more than 'n' different sites.

I'm listening to the most recent '[Security Now'](http://www.grc.com/sn/sn-189.htm) podcast which is raving about this feature as being great.

At the very same time I'm screaming NOOO! What the *#&$ -- because my site (as does many many others) includes the following (jQuery + SWFObject). i.e. I'm using [Google's CDN](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/) to host my jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.1/swfobject.js"></script>
```

So whats the deal - should I stop usin jQuery and swfobject from a CDN ?

Whats everybody else doing?

**Edit: ** I couldn't find out if they keep a list of 'trusted sites' or not, but according to [this](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/features/browse-privately.aspx) from Microsoft the InPrivate filtering is per session. So at least someone has to actively enable it every session.

> InPrivate Filtering is off by default and must be enabled on a
>   per-session basis. To use this
>   feature, select InPrivate Filtering
>   from the Safety menu. To access and
>   manage different filtering options for
>   Internet Explorer 8, select InPrivate
>   Filtering Settings from the Safety
>   menu. To end your InPrivate Browsing
>   session, simply close the browser
>   window.

Comment: And now MS themselves host jQuery on their own CDN...

Comment: Leave it to Microsoft to add a feature that could actually put a huge dent in the phishing/spyware/virus problem, and cripple it with a silly name (they're already trying to sell it, that's a problem), and per-session enabling requirement. Not to mention it won't "learn" and automatically block bad scripts, or add any value to an already flawed browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your site has content that people would not want cached (bank site, porn, or something else "sensitive"), then I would not use an externally hosted file. Or if your site is just totally broken if the file does not load I would consider it. But if your site is anything else, I wouldn't worry about it. I don't think this is a feature most people will use if they want to hide their tracks. And if they really want to, let them deal with the consequences.

Comment: this is the direction i'm leaning to - as soon as i saw the fact that it is session based and not permanent. if it is permanent then it is very scary (from a web dveloper standpoint), but if its temporary then the user will always know that they have it enabled.

Answer (score 3):

This may seem silly but since IE8 is out, why don't you test your site with InPrivate turned on and see how it behaves? Also if you can report back your findings here that would be great :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's a significant chance this will be disabled with InPrivate enabled, but it ultimately depends on each user's browsing habits.

If a user visits 10 sites in regular mode that all link to files from the same third-party domain, links to files on that domain will be blocked when InPrivate is enabled.

So while you won't be able to take advantage of the CDN, you should host files like this yourself if you need them to work reliably.

> InPrivate Blocking keeps a record of
>   third-party items like the one above
>   as you browse. When you choose to
>   browse with InPrivate, IE
>   automatically blocks sites that have
>   “seen” you across more than ten sites.
>
> You can also manually choose items to
>   block or allow, or obtain information
>   about the third-party content directly
>   from the site by clicking the “More
>   information from this website” link.
>   Note that Internet Explorer will only
>   record data for InPrivate Blocking
>   when you are in “regular” browsing
>   mode, as no browsing history is
>   retained while browsing InPrivate. An
>   easy way to think of it is that your
>   normal browsing determines which items
>   to block when you browse InPrivate.

Disclaimer: I haven't actually tested any of this as I don't have IE8, but the document you linked to is pretty clear about this.

Comment: you summarized my concern very well. the fact is that TONNES of people are doing this and i'm just concerned it'll be a big issue. im just going ahead and using google, but i'm just slightly confused about the apparent ticking time bomb. thsi question is pretty old - i just assigned some bounty to see if anyone else knew any more. im not losing sleep over it - but would be very interested to see where this is going. (especially since MS has their own CDN now). i didnt see anything in the documentation about globally allowed servers such as google/MS

Comment: I'm actually using Google's CDN myself and this wasn't something that I was aware about before (so thanks for raising the question!). My guess is that if this turns out to be a big problem MS will respond (maybe update IE8 with some sort of whitelist like you suggested?).

Answer (score 1):

You should host the JS files on your own site.

[Here's another reason](http://news.zdnet.com/2100-9595_22-302332.html?tag=nl.e539) to host the JS file on your site.

Comment: It is wrong because Michael is advising not to use Google CDN because they have some hours of downtime, when all the world knows that Google uptime and performance will be always best than yours.

Comment: wouldn't the uptime for an HTML page on your site match the uptime for a JS file on your site?  It will never matter if your JS has better uptime than your HTML, right?

Comment: Benefits of using Google's version: a) users may already have it cached, b) presumably Google can deliver the file itself faster than many others, and c) browsers have a limit of files they will download from one hostname in parallel, so this gets around it without having to setup additional subdomains.

Comment: While I can agree with Michael on this one, if you're really trying to cut down bandwidth use/speed up load times, it would be idea to use Google CDN, with a fallback to your own server.

Comment: True - but this wasn't a question about bandwidth use, it was about how to deal with InPrivate browsing in IE8.  Now with Chrome's Incongnito and FireFox's Private Browsing mode, you need to balance the use of Google CDN with your site's functionality when browsing in a private context.

Answer (score 1):

I've always wondered, would it be possible to have a safe fallback in the event the CDN is down/unavailable?

Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
       document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='local/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there would be a low percent of people using IE8 (*I think*), then turning on the option "InPrivate Browsing".  Google's CDN somehow says "it has a server near where the user accessing the website is, so that the performance is increased" (not directly quoted).  IE has caused me numerous problems in the past, and I dropped support for it.

Answer (score 0):

does it work from the domain name of the site e.g. ajax.googleapis.com or does it resolve the name? if it just logs the domain, couldn't you just wrap it in a CNAME e.g. js.yourdomain.com -> ajax.googleapis.com?